# Multiple header lines for different modes?

Tags: header-line

I would like to use both [tabbar-mode](https://github.com/dholm/tabbar) and [global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/semantic/Sticky-Func-Mode.html) at the same time.  Both of these use a [header line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html).  When I try to enable them both, one of them "wins" and I don't get the other.  Is it possible to get them to both work at the same time?

Comment: If you don't get a simple answer here, consider filing an Emacs enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: This is not possible.  You may wish to consider combining the two to create your own custom `header-line-format` that will only be one line; or, put some stuff in the `mode-line-format`; or, put some stuff in the frame-title.